# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS After Updating to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, redirect, nginx, drupal, server

After updating to Ubuntu 16, my website now has an issue with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. The website worked fine before the upgrade (It is running Drupal). NGINX -t returns the syntax is okay and the test was successful. Recovering from a backup also does not fix the problem.

Below I have my sites enabled file

```
server {
server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
root /root/to/dir;

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
#    return 403;
}

location ~ sites/default/files/.*php {
#   return 403;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
#    return 403;
}

# Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
    allow all;
}

# Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
# as Subversion or Git to store control files.
location ~ (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
}

location / {
    # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
     try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}

location ~* /sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

# Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

# In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in the middle,
# such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict, and only allows this pattern
# with the update.php front controller.  This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
# blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If you do not have
# any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a laxer rule, such as:
#   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
# The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL pattern with front
# controllers other than update.php in a future release.
location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

# Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
#location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

}

I understand it is in an endless loop of redirects but I cannot find the culprit.

My error log is displaying this:

```
"2017/09/13 07:21:33 [error] 3478#3478: *235 directory index of "/root/to/dir/" is forbidden, client: 100.00.000.000, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.0"
```

Which looks like it would be a permissions issue but the directory is set to 755

Removing $scheme// from the return 301 reveals the address as website.com/website.com/......website.com and returns 414 URI too large

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: See if apache anoid nginx , maybe services are in conflicts and run at same time

Comment: You configuration finishes on line 3. Nothing after the `return 301` gets seen. Is it an attempt to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`? Because it will not work, as it also tries to redirect `www.example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Comment: As @RichardSmith mentioned your config will never get past `return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;` You need to create a separate block for `example.com` server and there you can add this return statement

Comment: @RichardSmith TarunLalwani you guys certainly were correct. It now has opened up a new error I need to figure out... 

`connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream`